# Why is flask url_for too slow

Tags: python, flask

I tested it with this code:

```
from gevent import wsgi, monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<int:n>')
def index(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        url = url_for('index', n=i)
    return url 

wsgi.WSGIServer(('', 8000), app).serve_forever()
```

Results:

- `/1 Requests per second:    2721.94 [#/sec] (mean)`
- `/10 Requests per second:    1080.16 [#/sec] (mean)`
- `/100 Requests per second:    144.66 [#/sec] (mean)`

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I looking for way to increase url_for speed, because i used near 500 url_for on one page. With test context it works fine, this code takes 0.06 sec:

    ctx = app.test_request_context()
    ctx.push()

    started = time.time()
    for i in xrange(1000):
        url_for('index', n=i)
    print time.time() - started

Comment: How were you benchmarking it (there doesn't seem to be any reference to how you got the request per-second numbers)?

Comment: I tested it with apache ab.

Comment: As annoying as it is, you could construct the links manually instead of using `url_for`.

Comment: It indeed is quite slow. Slower than I expected at least. If it is critical for performance, I would indeed just use hardcoded strings to create the urls - can't imagine anything being faster than that. If you're truly interested, study https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/helpers.py#L184 and consider profiling it.

Comment: You test speed with development server. Create production env and test  on it. And use cache

Comment: No, I tested in the production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is kinda slow.

Good news is time complexity is linear, `O(1)`.

Below is cProfile dump

If I were a flask developer, I'd look at why url_for calls both `urljoin` and `urlsplit`. If I understand the werkzeug code correctly, it performs validation on the resulting url.

```
         13726316 function calls (13526316 primitive calls) in 16.918 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   400000    0.272    0.000    0.453    0.000 <string>:8(__new__)
   100000    0.120    0.000    0.140    0.000 app.py:1484(inject_url_defaults)
   200000    0.762    0.000    1.052    0.000 datastructures.py:316(__init__)
   100000    0.132    0.000    0.395    0.000 globals.py:16(_lookup_object)
   100000    0.913    0.000   16.996    0.000 helpers.py:250(url_for)
   300000    0.527    0.000    0.846    0.000 local.py:156(top)
   100000    0.136    0.000    0.645    0.000 local.py:289(_get_current_object)
   100000    0.112    0.000    0.901    0.000 local.py:333(__getattr__)
   300000    0.264    0.000    0.320    0.000 local.py:66(__getattr__)
   200000    0.059    0.000    0.059    0.000 routing.py:1199(update)
   200000    0.147    0.000    0.147    0.000 routing.py:1455(get_host)
400000/200000    0.802    0.000    6.297    0.000 routing.py:1520(_partial_build)
   200000    1.791    0.000   14.382    0.000 routing.py:1541(build)
   400000    0.153    0.000    0.153    0.000 routing.py:1601(<genexpr>)
   200000    1.830    0.000    5.181    0.000 routing.py:701(build)
   200000    0.275    0.000    0.275    0.000 routing.py:743(suitable_for)
   200000    0.256    0.000    0.256    0.000 routing.py:928(to_url)
   400000    0.935    0.000    2.816    0.000 urlparse.py:128(urlparse)
   400000    1.010    0.000    1.428    0.000 urlparse.py:159(urlsplit)
   200000    0.175    0.000    0.274    0.000 urlparse.py:214(urlunparse)
   200000    0.099    0.000    0.099    0.000 urlparse.py:224(urlunsplit)
   200000    1.961    0.000    5.637    0.000 urlparse.py:242(urljoin)
     5263    0.004    0.000    0.019    0.000 urlparse.py:62(clear_cache)
   400000    0.483    0.000    0.783    0.000 urls.py:36(_quote)
   400000    0.509    0.000    1.534    0.000 urls.py:369(url_quote)
   100000    0.068    0.000    0.068    0.000 wrappers.py:85(blueprint)
   505263    0.235    0.000    0.235    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x10d044248}
   200000    0.101    0.000    0.169    0.000 {getattr}
   100000    0.114    0.000    0.114    0.000 {hasattr}
  2000000    0.642    0.000    0.642    0.000 {isinstance}
   505263    0.073    0.000    0.073    0.000 {len}
   200000    0.041    0.000    0.041    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
   600000    0.127    0.000    0.127    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     5263    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 {method 'clear' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     5263    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
   100000    0.072    0.000    0.072    0.000 {method 'find' of 'unicode' objects}
   700000    0.231    0.000    0.231    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
   400000    0.105    0.000    0.105    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
   200000    0.116    0.000    0.116    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
   200000    0.157    0.000    0.157    0.000 {method 'join' of 'unicode' objects}
   200000    0.134    0.000    0.134    0.000 {method 'lstrip' of 'unicode' objects}
   300000    0.052    0.000    0.052    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'dict' objects}
   200000    0.079    0.000    0.079    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
   400000    0.249    0.000    0.249    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
   200000    0.183    0.000    0.183    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   400000    0.339    0.000    0.339    0.000 {method 'split' of 'unicode' objects}
   300000    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 {thread.get_ident}
```

I have 2-3 practical solutions for you:

- cache (most common) url_for results
- offload url_for computation to client/js
- hardcode url generation

If you have RESTful API with numeric id's the last option may look like this:

```
datum_url_template = url_for("datum", n=999)
def url_for_datum(n):
    return datum_url_template.replace("999", str(n))

foobar_url_template = url_for("foobar", n=777)
def url_for_foobar(n):
    return foobar_url_template.replace("777", str(n))
```